# Firefox textarea placeholder text getting lost

Tags: jquery, firefox, placeholder

Browser:
Firefox only

Issue:
On click of a btn I am clearing the textarea using jQuery $('.textarea').val('')

The textarea gets cleared but the placeholder also disappears. If I click inside the textarea, the placeholder text comes back. I tried .focus().blur() after clearing the textarea but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle to re-create this issue? Doesn't appear the same for me http://jsfiddle.net/d4KaY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't appear that way for me http://jsfiddle.net/d4KaY/

But even if it does, you can manually set the placeholder using jQuery:

```
$('textarea').val('').attr("placeholder", "Your placeholder here");
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d4KaY/1/)**